# How can I programmaticaly check what is allowed input of a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I would like to "clear" a JFormattedTextField programmatically but if I simply call 
txtAny.setText("") it is doesn't work cause textfield's regex pattern 
in my case:

```
private final String FORMATTER_STRING_FLOAT =
 "[\\p{Digit}\\p{Cntrl}]{1,32}(\\.[\\p{Digit}\\p{Cntrl}]{0,2})?";
```

that requires at least one digit.

So my question is: how can I obtain a regex pattern of a JFormattedTextField 
for  at least further manual partial processing?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148336/jformattedtextfield-is-not-properly-cleared which suggests that (as of Java 5, at least) there are limitations on clearing JFormattedTextField

Comment: See also [Why is JFormattedTextField Evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320117/why-is-jformattedtextfield-evil)

Comment: should be simple and possible, there isn't reason be confused thread linked by @DNA, depends of your code in the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) form

Answer (score 2):

Call `setText(anyValidString)` rather than `setText("")`