# Java JTextfields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Just a quick question,
How do i ensure my JtextField only accepts numeric values?
I want it to to diplsy an error message if the user entered anything else 
thank you

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield/1313448#1313448 - no need for nasty error messasges.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).  Construct it using a [`NumberFormatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html) and it will only accept numbers.

The `JFormattedTextField` has a bunch of configurable options that let you decide how bad input is handled.  I recommend looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a key event listener and check each char typed in or there are document formatters (NumberFormatter) you can install that will not allow you to enter anything but a number.

Answer (score 0):

Associate a key listener with the text field and check for the value just inserted. If value inserted is not an integer, then prompt error.

Comment: I like this idea but but how would i check for value entered? might you have an example code? thanks

Answer (score -1):

I use this trick.

```
private void myTextFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
try{
int i = Integer.parseInt(myTextField.getText());
}
catch(Exception ex){
//Show error message here with 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input...!");
myTexTField.setText("");
}
}
```

Comment: keyListeners are too low-level for such a task, they are not safe enough: it'll miss pasted texted.