# Disable input some symbols to JTextField

Tags: java, swing

How can I disable input of any symbol except digits to `JTextField`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java JTextfields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442004/java-jtextfields)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to accept only numeric values in a JTextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield)

Comment: It sounds as though a JSpinner *might* be what the user actually needs here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Option 1) change your JTextField with a JFormattedTextField, like this:

```
try {
   MaskFormatter mascara = new MaskFormatter("##.##");
   JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(mascara);
   textField.setValue(new Float("12.34"));
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

Option 2) capture user's input from keyboard, like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if ( ((c < '0') || (c > '9')) && (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
         e.consume();  // ignore event
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer is `JFormattedTextField`.  [See my answer on this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442004/java-jtextfields):

> You can use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).  Construct it using a [`NumberFormatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html) and it will only accept numbers.
>
> The `JFormattedTextField` has a bunch of configurable options that let you decide how bad input is handled.  I recommend looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

```
 amountField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
```

You can also create your own format to customize.

Answer (score 3):

Just consume all chars that is not a digit like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JTextField() {{
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar()))
                    e.consume();
            }
        });
    }});

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: That wont handle, for example, paste. It's also rather dependent upon how the PL&F implements the `JTextField` - wouldn't work for a `JComboBox` (probably!).

Answer (score 3):

**For a better user experience**

Others have mentioned the use of JFormattedTextField or KeyListeners to prevent invalid data from being entered but from a usability point of view I find it very annoying to start typing into a field and nothing happens.

To provide a better user experience you can allow the user to enter non-numeric values in the field but use a validator to provide feedback to the user and disable the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom `KeyListener` that intercepts key strokes and doesn't propogate invalid key strokes to the `JTextField`.

Comment: when i use keylisteners, the symbol will appear in field and after that it will be remove. But I want only the symbol to appear if it is a digit symbol

Comment: If your listener consumes the `KeyEvent` then the field never hears about it. I see that dacwe has added just such an example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Have a look.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{

  char c = e.getKeyChar();

  if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') ||    
     (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
     (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {

        getToolkit().beep();

        e.consume();

  }

}
```