# how to filter certain characters in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How to prevent user from entering certain charcters in 'JTextField' and if enters that character is entered ,do not show it in the textfield

Comment: not this is about DocumentFilter, KeyListener is proper only in the case that there is key shortcut with three or more keys pressed in the same time,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  char c = e.getKeyChar();
  if (//Write your condition here) {
     e.consume();  // ignore event
}});
```

More on the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863850/disable-input-some-symbols-to-jtextfield)

Comment: -1,  You should NOT be using a KeyListener. Swing has newer and better API's for this problem. For example try pasting text into your text field and see what happens.

Comment: Use document listener instead

Answer (score 7):

You can either use a JFormattedTextField or create a custom [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Comment: Implementation example: https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0197.html