# Best way to remap input of certain characters/keys to a JTextComponent?

Tags: java, swing, input, keylistener, jtextcomponent

I am working on a `JTextPane` that works (almost) exactly like the tags input field here on stackoverflow. For that I am converting text to components as soon as a user hits enter, tab or space. Naturally I do not want any of those characters to actually be input to the text pane. I found this solution, SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TagTextPane extends JTextPane {

    public TagTextPane() {
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "finalizeTag");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "finalizeTag");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "focusNext");
        this.getActionMap().put("focusNext", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                finalizeTag();
                transferFocus();
            }
        });
        this.getActionMap().put("finalizeTag", new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                finalizeTag();
            }
        });
    }

    private void finalizeTag() {
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) getDocument();
        Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(getCaretPosition() - 1);
        int start = element.getStartOffset();
        int len = element.getEndOffset() - start;
        String tag = "";
        try {
            tag = this.getDocument().getText(start, len);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        }
        this.setSelectionStart(start);
        this.setSelectionEnd(start + len);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(tag);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        this.insertComponent(label);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TagTextPaneTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TagTextPane tPane = new TagTextPane();
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tPane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hitting "tab" usually causes a tab character to be inserted and hitting "enter" usually causes a line break to be entered, as well as hitting "space" causes a space to be entered. The weird thing is that my code stops line breaks and tabs from being entered, but still allows spaces to be entered normally, while performing the intended action.

1. Why does this approach behave differently for those keys?
2. How can I stop the space from being entered? (Maybe I want to extend this behavior to commas and the like later on.)
3. How can I optimally control the behavior of certain characters and keystrokes in a `JTextComponent`? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863998/1654255), where the suggestion is to use a `KeyListener`, but I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703644/how-to-filter-certain-characters-in-jtextfield), where Rob Camick points out, why a `KeyListener` should not be used. So should I rather use a `DocumentFilter`, or is that breaking a butterfly on a wheel?
4. Is this even the best way to build this kind of tag input field?

Comment: See [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) about the special action name "none".

Comment: @trashgod I have read that, but it I interpret that to mean, that if I do not want the key to cause any other behavior (which is what I want), then I cannot use the "none" action. But the point is that I am not using the "none" action, I am already using a properly named action.

Comment: Oops, I though `SPACE` had a binding. Maybe use a `DocumentListener`?

Comment: @trashgod Maybe. For that I would need to understand this better. Could you point me to a tutorial or something, where I can understand the exact chain of events that unfolds, between the user hitting a key, and the programmatically intended action beginning?

Comment: See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) and other [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+DocumentListener)

Comment: @trashgod You didn't read me right: I want to understand how the key stroke is propagated. Through what and where it causes behavior. I am familiar with Listeners of all kinds, but the processing of a key stroke is more than that.

Comment: The easiest way to see is to break in the debugger.

Comment: @trashgod What do I break? Where do I break? I cannot set a breakpoint in code that belongs to the JVM, can I? I want to see which component or listener or whateveritis receives first notice of a key stroke, and what happens next. I would not only like to see this in this exact case, but to get a general understanding of this process.

Comment: A complete tutorial is beyond the scope of SO; yes, you can break in Java library classes; I use NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "finalizeTag");
```

This is handling the keyPressed event for the space character.

You want to handle the keyTyped event of the space character:

```
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(' '), "finalizeTag");
```

Comment: Aha, "If `typed`, `pressed` or `released` is not specified, `pressed` is assumed."

Comment: That answers my questions no 2 and 3, but does it answer no 1? The point is, that I register the events for all three keys the same way (assuming `pressed`), but they behave differently, since neither a tab nor a newline is actually typed. I could understand, if the new line worked differently, because it is not the same character on different systems, but the tab should be, right?

Comment: @SheridanVespo, all keys behave the same, that is, your finalizeTag Action is invoked. When you press the spacebar this also generates a keyTyped event which is the event that actually adds the " " to the document after the finalizeTag Action has executed. The Tab and Enter keys don't generate a keyTyped event so nothing is added to the document.