# How to validate inputs on JTextField in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

everyone, I am writing an interactive graphical user interface program. basically it accepts all inputs and display information on TextArea below. but it will validate all inputs if it is empty or null.
**My question is that, for example, first name is empty, how can it loop back at textField (first name field)? and retype again without further going ?**

I was using a do while loop, but it only works when I use JOptionPane windows to pop out. let me clarify my question: What I want is that when the first name field is null or empty, the user needs to retype again from textfield instead of a window, I don't want "JOPtionPane.showmessageDialog " window coming out
Thanks

image is here

[graphic interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbBI4.png)

[do while loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QizyR.png)

```
do{
        whetherContinue=true;

        FName=TxtFname.getText();
        if(TxtFname.getText().isEmpty()){
            FName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please type your First Name");
            TxtFname.setText(FName);
        }
        else{

        }
        if (FName==null)
            System.exit(1);
    try{
        if (FName.isEmpty())
            throw new ArithmeticException("First name can not be empty!");
        whetherContinue = false;
    }catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The first name can not be empty! Please type again");
    }
    }while(whetherContinue); //First Name while
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: We hope you post your codes and images here directly for easy surfing.

Comment: question in this form isn't answerable here, for more informations to read FAQ, especially the part about MCVE

Comment: sorry for any confusion here, I posted my code here, But I don't know why you have to click to view it.

Comment: let me clarify my question: What I want is that when the first name field is null or empty, the user needs to retype again from textfield instead of a window, I don't want "JOPtionPane.showmessageDialog " window coming out.

Answer (score 0):

try the focus listner for the empty input problem 
when the focus is lost from your component check it's text i the text is empty than go back to the same component by requestFocus method

```
 FocusListener focus_event = new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if(textField.getText().isEmpty())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Please enter","erruer",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    textField.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };
        textField.addFocusListener(focus_event);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this method, it prevents the user from entering non-numerical characters as they type.
You capture user's input from keyboard, like this if you are taking numbers:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if ( ((c < '0') || (c > '9')) && (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
         e.consume();  // ignore event
      }
   }
});
```

Based on this approach, you can do for characters that you want.

OR change your JTextField with a JFormattedTextField, like this:

```
try {
   MaskFormatter mascara = new MaskFormatter("##.##");
   JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(mascara);
   textField.setValue(new Float("12.34"));
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

**Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863850/disable-input-some-symbols-to-jtextfield) with other approaches as well.**

Comment: Consider using a custom [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) or a [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) - KeyListener won't handle things like paste actions and/or dnd

Comment: That is very true but I added a reference with other approaches

Comment: Maybe I would have to add that up there.