# One JButton to call member functions based on user input

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

Given a GUI app, a user will select one of the two radio buttons, `JRadioButton a`, or `JRadioButton b`. Depending on his selection, he will enter different inputs. However, to calculate a formula, he will click on a regular button, `JButton c`.

However, the trouble ensues when more than two member functions are called within the `ActionListener`.

```
      c = new JButton( "c" );
      c.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          cActionPerformed( e );
        }
      });
```

For within the `ActionEvent`, we have,

```
    public void cActionPerformed( ActionEvent ev ) {
      try {
        double f = foo.blah( x, y );
        double b = bar.meh( y, z );
      }
      catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, "Error message.", "Error", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION
        );
      }
    }
```

However, the program only goes down one level in the call stack, returning the `catch` exception dialog. How do I make it so that when the user presses button `c`, depending on whether `a` or `b` is selected, he gets `f` or `b`, respectively?

Comment: `For within the ActionEvent, we have,` better would be post an  [SSCCE](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sscce.html)

Comment: Not enough context: Must both `blah` and `meh` be evaluated for a given click? Are `x` and `z` mutually exclusive? Can inputs be [verified](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11818946/230513) on entry?

Comment: What's the exception been thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getSource()` method inherited from `EventObject` to discriminate the source of the event.

Example:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == button1) {
      setSize(300, 200);
      doLayout();
    } else if (event.getSource() == button2) {
      setSize(400, 300);
      doLayout();
    } else if (event.getSource() == button3) {
      setSize(500, 400);
      doLayout();
    }
```

Comment: But the getSource() will return the button clicked. not the radio button which is selected..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isSelected()` option of a radio button.

```
JRadioButton f = new JRadioButton();
JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton();

public void cActionPerformed( ActionEvent ev ) {
      try {
        if(f.isSelected()){

            double f = foo.blah( x, y );

         } else if(b.isSelected()){

            double b = bar.meh( y, z );

         } else { // If none is selected
            // Do something
         }
      }
      catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, "Error message.", "Error", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It threw the exception I stated in the `catch` block.

Comment: Are you sure this is related? From where does this exception get thrown? foo and bar? what cause it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the program entering the `catch` block has nothing to do with determining which radio button is selected.  The only way it can enter into the catch block is if a `NumberFormatException` is being thrown.  The only way a `NumberFormatException` can be thrown is if it is coming from `foo.blah( x, y );` or `bar.meh( y, z );`.

So - you need to figure out why that exception is being thrown by your functions first.  Then you can apply La bla bla's answer.

A good way of figuring out where the error is being thrown is to use `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch`.  This will print a stack trace to console output pointing you to the exact line of code causing the problem.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at foobar.cActionPerformed(foobarFrame.java:86)
at foobar$3.actionPerformed(foobarFrame.java:54)
...
`

Comment: So line 86 of your "LoanCalculatorFrame" class is throwing the exception.  Which method is on that line?  Can we see the source code for that method?  I'm guessing you're converting a String to a number in that method.  This is what the java docs says about this exception: "Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format."

Comment: `double amt = Double.parseDouble( loanTextField.getText() );`

Comment: So the problem is that the text in `loanTextField` can't be parsed as a double because it's not in the right format. If you print out the text to the console window, you'll probably be able to see the problem (use `System.out.println("'" + loanTextField.getText() + "'");` - that way you can see any extra spaces at the ends)

Comment: I'm sorry - I must have misrepresented my intentions.  I was willing to hold your hand helping you troubleshoot your problem because it's a good learning experience (for you).  I think we've found the problem - you have a space or a % or some non-number character in the textbox you're trying to convert to a number.  I'm pretty sure you can figure it out from here... (it's going to be the thing that's not one of these characters: `0123456789-.`)  I'm going to sleep now - best of luck with finding the culprit!

Comment: Oh - And I should also mention that if the field is blank, that exception will also be thrown (you can't convert an empty string to a number).  Come to think of it - this is probably what's happening.

Comment: Is it supposed to be blank, so that the user can enter something?

Comment: Yes - but if it's blank when you're trying to convert it into a number, you're going to get an exception.  So you can wrap an `if` statement around it to make sure it's not blank before you do any calculations with it.