# FocusListener on JTextField not working

Tags: java, swing, focuslistener

I've created an application that uses FocusListener to make sure a text fieid's value is always positive. When the user inputs negative value and then click the "tab" key to move focus away from the text field, the value will be multiplied by -1 so that the resulted value is positive. However, when I ran the application, the text field didn't change. I am not sure what I did wrong, and will appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AlwaysPositive extends JFrame implements FocusListener {
JTextField posField = new JTextField("30",5);

public AlwaysPositive() {
    super("AlwaysPositive");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JTextField posField = new JTextField("30",5);
    JButton ok= new JButton("ok");
    posField.addFocusListener(this);
    pane.add(posField);
    pane.add(ok);
    add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent event) {
    try {
        float pos = Float.parseFloat(posField.getText());
        if (pos < 0) 
            pos = pos*-1;
        posField.setText("" + pos);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        posField.setText("0");
    }
}

public void focusGained(FocusEvent event) {
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    AlwaysPositive ap = new AlwaysPositive();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are shadowing your variables

You declare

```
 JTextField posField = new JTextField("30",5);
```

As an instance variable, but in your constructor, you redeclare it again...

```
public AlwaysPositive() {
    //...
    JTextField posField = new JTextField("30",5);
    posField.addFocusListener(this);
    //...
}
```

Add attach the focus listener to it, but in the `focusLost` method, you are referring to the instance variable, which isn't the one that is actually on the screen

Start by changing the declaration within the constructor

```
public AlwaysPositive() {
    //...
    posField = new JTextField("30",5);
    posField.addFocusListener(this);
    //...
}
```

However, there are better solutions to use then `FocusListener`.

For example, you could use an `InputVerifier` that will allow you to verify the value of the field and make decisions about whether focus should be moved or not.

Take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) and [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) in particular

You could also use a `DocumentFilter` to restrict what the user can actually enter, filtering the input as the user types it.  Take a look at [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) and [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) in particular.

You can also take a look at [these examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more ideas

Comment: Today, i have explained an issue with `InputVerifier` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565839/input-verifier-effect-not-work-by-click-just-work-by-tab-button/19566591#19566591). Though the problem is not with verifier, but with underlying use case and design.  would you mind to have a look ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create object of same name inside a method, the listener is set to the method object and not to the Class object.