# How do i make a check for in the input is a number or not in swing?

Tags: java, swing, input, numbers

So i was making an application where the user enters an input, and when he clicks the button it executes a command, however the input has to be an integer, so i added a check but even when i enter an integer is gives me an error saying "you can enter numbers only!"

heres my code :

```
        String itemId = textField1.getText();
        String itemAmount = textField2.getText();

        int id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);

        if (!Double.isNaN(id) || !Double.isNaN(amount)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "You can only enter numbers!"
            );
```

even after i enter numbers to the textFields i still cannot pass this test, why and how can i fix this ? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restricting JTextField input to Integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers)

Comment: That question asked a lot of times here, try to search, before ask that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Double.isNaN(id)
```

> Returns true if the specified number is a Not-a-Number (NaN) value,
>   false otherwise.

But your `id` and your `amout` are Integers so it will return false and you do `!Double.isNaN(id)` and invert the boolean, so the result is true. Its only an logical failure. Remove the `!`.

```
if (Double.isNaN(id) || Double.isNaN(amount)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only enter numbers!");
}
```

**Note:**

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
int amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);
```

Sourround this two lines with an try and catch block, otherwise you will get an `NumberFormatException` if the input is not numeric.

```
try
{
    int id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);+
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    //print your error here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> however the input has to be an integer, so i added a check but even
>   when i enter an integer is gives me an error saying "you can enter
>   numbers only!"

there are two ways, to use

- JFormattedTextField with number formatter, JSpinner with SpinnerNumberModel
- add DocumentFilter to JTextField

Comment: *"`JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel`"*  Happiness.  :)  This best (IMO) approach is the way to go.

Comment: +1 Totally agree. If people have worked hard to give us the solution to the input-validation problem through such components (`JSpinner` and `JFormattedTextField`), why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can just do it like this:

```
String itemId = textField1.getText();
String itemAmount = textField2.getText();
int id;
int amount;
try{
    id = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
    amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only enter numbers!");
}
```

If `itemID` and `itemAmount` value is not parse-able, means non-digit was entered

Comment: Catch `NumberFormatException`, not `Exception`. Otherwise, if something else is broken, and you get a `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it will still say "You can only enter numbers!" when the problem is nothing to do with entering numbers or not.

Comment: doesn't matter. `Exception` will still catch the `NumberFormatException`. But okay, i'll modify it.(I don't think `NullPointerException` or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` can happen inside that 2 lines try block :))

Comment: @TAsk  *"The Simplest One!!"*  Way no!  You should check out `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel`for this, as mentioned in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22629861/418556).  Much simpler than trying to force a square peg (integer) into a round hole (text field).  :)  For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021773/418556)..

Comment: @TAsk .. or [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111095/418556) or [this slightly more complicated example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556) (which uses 4 spinners to trigger a `ChangeListener` to update the GUI)..

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache's [StringUtils.isNumeric()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.String%29) method, if you don't want to use JFormattedTextField