# How to validate a JTextField of email ID with a regex in swing code?

Tags: java, regex, swing, netbeans-6.9

I have tried a lot for this validation but I'm not getting where to put the following code

```
String expression="^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";.
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: The reliable way to validate an email address is to send an email and ask for a reply.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson but in a textfield how to validate the email id with regex?

Comment: in a information page i have to validate & m developing a desktop app.

Comment: When do you want to check the JTextField? Only when the user clicks a validate button or when he leaves the JTextField?

Comment: @Rob when he clickes submit button it should check whether the entered email id is in correct format or not?
I dont bother about the existence of the email id.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1313390/1076463) and [my answer containing example code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463). That is for numeric input but you can easily write your own `java.text.Format` based on that regex to accept only emails

Answer (score 9):

I hope this will help. When you Click on Submit button on SWING UI, in actionListener write the validation code.

```
   Emailvalidator emailValidator = new Emailvalidator();
   if(!emailValidator.validate(emailField.getText().trim())) {
        System.out.print("Invalid Email ID");
        /*
           Action that you want to take. For ex. make email id field red
           or give message box saying invalid email id.
        */
   }
```

This is the seperate class EmailValidator

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class EmailValidator {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    public EmailValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    }

    /**
     * Validate hex with regular expression
     * 
     * @param hex
     *            hex for validation
     * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
     */
    public boolean validate(final String hex) {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
        return matcher.matches();

    }
}
```

On a side note, this will enable you that the entered email id is in the correct format. If you want to validate the id, send an email containing a confirmation no and ask the user to enter that number on your UI and then proceed.

Comment: for this whether i have to create a new class or in the source panel of my Design panel i can write?

Comment: Its good practise as you may require to validate email id on multiple screen. You may write this as a seperate utility class, and use it as and when required.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try this code.
But in the buttonevent i have to check the entered email id is correct or not?
So for that what shoul i do?

Answer (score 0):

The format of an e-mail address can get [pretty complex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).  In fact, its complexity is almost [legendary](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

The `InternetAddress` class in [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/) is a much more reliable way to parse an e-mail address than a regular expression.