# Controlling what a JFormattedTextField returns

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, formatter, jformattedtextfield

I intialize my JFormattedTextField like this :

```
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
field.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("#0.00"))));
```

Now, when I enter any number with decimal points, the field returns a Double. When I enter a number without decimal points, it returns a Long. Is there a way to setup the Formatter so it returns a Double even when the number entered has no decimal points ?

Comment: Set your own `Format` on the `JFormattedTextField`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463) for an example

Comment: Or use `doubleValue()` maybe?

Comment: @Jimmy T. doubleValue() would work ofcourse, but I find it a bit unwieldly checking every returned value whether it´s a Long or already a Double.

Comment: @Robin the example is just what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Every `Number` has a method `doubleValue()`. No need to check the type.

Comment: Yes, you´re right. Now I am casting getValue() to Long or Double as needed, but I could cast to Number and call doubleValue() or longValue() depending on my needs.