# JFormattedTextField for Double still takes characters

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, double, jformattedtextfield

I have a JFormattedTextField where the user would input prices, I have this, but if I type a character, it'll let me anyway. I need this text field to only read numbers or , from the keyboard, and ignore if it's a char. How should I change it in order to make it work?

```
JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
        formattedTextField.setBounds(25, 330, 56, 20);
        contentPanel.add(formattedTextField);
        formattedTextField.setValue(new Double(10.0));
```

Comment: This post should help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313390/is-there-any-way-to-accept-only-numeric-values-in-a-jtextfield

Answer (score 4):

You need to set a Formatter:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(f);
```

Take a look: 
[Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) 
and
[NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Then try this:

```
PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr) 
        throws BadLocationException 
    {
        fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
    } 
    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) 
        throws BadLocationException 
    {
        fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);  // remove non-digits
    }
});

JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField();
field.setDocument(doc);
```

Comment: still doesn't work with that

Comment: Why would you want to use a `DocumentFilter` in combination with a `JFormattedTextField`. What is the added value of the `JFormattedTextField` in this case ?

Comment: Just to emblematize that this TextField got a formatted Content, but you are right the whole purpose of JFormattedTextField are missed here.

Answer (score 0):

A `JFormattedTextField` can be used for many things, it can be also used to filter dates or phone numbers. You will either need to set a `NumberFormater` to the `TextField` or you use the DocumentFilter (works with JTextField only too).

Check this code snippet, that's how you allow only digits in JTextField, by using DocumentFilter, as the most effeciive way :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

public class InputInteger
{
    private JTextField tField;
    private MyDocumentFilter documentFilter;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Integer Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        tField = new JTextField(10);
        ((AbstractDocument)tField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(
                new MyDocumentFilter());        
        contentPane.add(tField); 

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new InputInteger().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class MyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter
{   
    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp
            , int offset, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                throws BadLocationException
    {
        int len = string.length();
        boolean isValidInteger = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
            {
                isValidInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidInteger)
            super.insertString(fp, offset, string, aset);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fp, int offset
                    , int length, String string, AttributeSet aset)
                                        throws BadLocationException
    {
        int len = string.length();
        boolean isValidInteger = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i)))
            {
                isValidInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isValidInteger)
            super.replace(fp, offset, length, string, aset);
        else
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```