# How to make JTextField into String/Long?

Tags: java, swing, parsing, methods, jtextfield

Currently Having my fields like that:

```
 final JTextField PID = new JTextField("Product ID", 7);
 frame.getContentPane().add(PID);
```

My method:

```
public StockItem(Long id, String name, String desc, double price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.price = price;
}
```

Trying to use this method with values from my `JTextField`s, but it does not allow to use `JTextField`s under my Long/String/double places.
Is there any way how I could convert my `JTextField`s into the required things without editing my Method.

Comment: A `JTextField` will always contain text (String). You can parse, transform, do whatever you want with that. If you want to have a UI control, that allows only numbers, then you can use `JSpinner` for example.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463) for an example using `JFormattedTextField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the text field text and parse it.

```
long l = Long.parseLong(PID.getText());
double d = Double.parseDouble(PID.getText());
```

Comment: Please beware that you have to try catch the parsing as the textfild may contain something that is not a long or double. Check this article: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00011.shtml

Comment: Can I do anything like that with a String too?

Comment: String s = PID.getText();

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **PID.getText()** to get the text, and then you can convert it to whatever you want, like this:

```
try{
    long id = Long.parseLong(PID.getText());
    String name = PNAME.getText();
    String description = PDESC.getText();
    double price = Double.parseDouble(PPRICE.getText());
}catch(Exception e){}
```

I have used the **try-catch** block because if the user enters something else instead of long in the PID, then it will catch the exception.