# How do we test if JFormattedTextField is empty?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` that is meant for user to enter phone number. My phone number is taking the following format :`+### ###-###-###`. I want to check for empty string before I save the phone number to a database. The problem is I am not able to check/determine if the field is empty. When I print `field.getText().length()` it outputs 16  meaning some characters are already in the field. How do I check if the user has entered some characters?

Below is my code:

```
public class JTextFiledDemo {

private JFrame frame;

JTextFiledDemo() throws ParseException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    iniGui();
}

private void iniGui() throws ParseException {

    JButton login = new JButton("Test");
    JFormattedTextField phone = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter(
            "+### ###-###-###"));

    frame.add(phone);
    frame.add(login);
    frame.pack();

    login.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The length of input is :"
                + phone.getText().length());

    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JTextFiledDemo tf = new JTextFiledDemo();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
      }

   }
```

Comment: Use a `java.text.Format` instead of a `MaskFormatter` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463)) and the problem will disappear.

Comment: @Robin Well, thanks let me look into it, for now I have used the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used the [isEditValid()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#isEditValid()) method to check the contents

```
 final boolean editValid = phone.isEditValid();
 showMessageDialog(frame, "The length of input is :" + phone.getText().length() + ".  It is " + (editValid ? "" : "not ") + "valid!");
```

Comment: Well, this is what I was looking for - let implement it.