# Restrict JTextField to only accept certain characters

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have 4 `JTextFields` that should only accept certain characters:

1. binary digits (`0`, `1`)
2. octal digits, so (`0` - `7`)
3. all digits (`0` - `9`)
4. all hexadecimal characters (`0` - `9`, `a` - `f`, `A` - `F`)

The user must not be able to input a *forbidden* character.

I know how I could validate the input afterwards, but not how to filter it.

---

I tried using a `MaskFormatter`, but then I can't enter anything at all.

```
MaskFormatter binaryFormatter = new MaskFormatter();
binaryFormatter.setValidCharacters("01");
JFormattedTextField binaryText = new JFormattedTextField(binaryFormatter);
```

Comment: Can you share the code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use a DocumentFilter on a normal JTextField instead

Comment: how? can you give me a code example

Comment: [Implementing a DocumntFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Comment: You could pass the formatted text field a [`MaskFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) which specifies valid characters

Comment: Convert your requirements into a `java.text.Format`, and use it in combination with the `JFormattedTextField`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to format the value, you want to filter the content.  Use a `DocumentFilter` on a plain on `JTextField`

Start by having a look at [Implementing a DocumntFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details...

As an example, a "binary filter", which will only accept `0` and `1`

```
public class BinaryDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    @Override
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            String text, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char ch = text.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '0' || ch == '1') {
                buffer.append(ch);
            }
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
            int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (length > 0) {
            fb.remove(offset, length);
        }
        insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
    }
}
```

Which can be applied directly to the field's `Document`:

```
JTextField binaryField = new JTextField(10);
((AbstractDocument)binaryField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new BinaryDocumentFilter());
```

Comment: at super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), **attr**);

Comment: and at **@Override** public void replace(){}

Comment: @Scriptim You're importing the wrong `AttributeSet`, you need `javax.swing.text.AttributeSet` and forgive me, but I've been using this technique for more the 15 years and works just fine.  The `DocumentFilter` is the best mechanism for restricting (or filtering) content into text components

Comment: Is it possible that `new StringBuilder(text.length())` was intended to be `new StringBuilder(text)`? Otherwise an empty `StringBuilder` of some size is created, though I don't understand how `buffer.charAt(i)` would ever yield something useful, since the buffer is not filled. Am I not seeing something?

Comment: @Koenigsberg First, we create a `StringBuffer` of the same length as in the coming text (as this is the maximum number of characters we will need - avoids the possibility that the `StringBuffer` will need to expand it's internal cache).  We then go through the text and only include `0` or `1` characters, all the rest are discarded. And `buffer.charAt(i);` should probably be `text.charAt(i);`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay. So my assumption about the buffer being empty in the original code was correct.