# How can I validate date and time entered in JTextField using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, date, jtextfield

I want to validate data entered by user in 'date and time' `JTextField` with (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS )  this format , please help me to get out of this, am not getting any idea.

How to validate entered data with this format (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS)?

Comment: If you have no idea how to even start this, I doubt you're suited to programming. Perhaps go into a simpler job. *"any help is appreciated,"* Don't forget to ask if the customer would like fries with their order.

Comment: Use a `JFormattedTextField` with a `SimpleDataFormat`, similar to what is done [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13424140/1076463).

Answer (score 1):

You can validate like this, if exception you need to notify user that it is not a valid format

```
    try {
        Date date = null;
        String inputDate = "2016-01-07 10:11:30.500";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        date = dateFormat.parse(inputDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException parseException) { 
        //Code should be added to handle invalid date format
    }
```

Comment: Code comment was added to say that custom code should be written to handle if date is invalid.

Comment: thanks for pointing, i have updated